# How to map URL Query String Parameter to a request header in AWS API Gateway

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I would like to secure AWS API Gateway endpoint with an API Key. However the API key must be sent as part of the query parameter. There is no way to instruct the service that uses this endpoint to send the key (x-api-key) in the header.

So I would like this request:
https://api_id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/?x-api-key=KEY

to automatically consider x-api-key as the API key when a request is made. Is there a straight way to achieve this in AWS API Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported by API Gateway and is not recommended on a security basis since URLs (including query string parameters) are commonly logged and/or cached by both clients and servers.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: I have no control over the client. All I can do is give the client a call-back url. Is blocking IP range a secure way? What could we do as a work-around.

Comment: "API keys are not meant as a security mechanism for controlling access to an API", see [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html). They are used to enforce usage plans. Depending on the application the distinction might be of little consequence, it sucks that you can't pass the key as a query param

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to use an [API Gateway Custom Authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)

But then the question is how to use enforce usage plans...

Comment: Is that even possible? My reading of http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#api-gateway-custom-authorizer-output is that only request headers can be sent to Custom Authorizers: "The custom header mapping expression is of the method.request.header.<name> format, where <name> is the name of a custom authorization header submitted as part of the client request"

Answer (score 0):

You can use API Gateway Lambda Authorizers.

> An Amazon API Gateway Lambda authorizer (formerly known as a custom authorizer) is a Lambda function that you provide to control access to your API methods. A Lambda authorizer uses bearer token authentication strategies, such as OAuth or SAML. It can also use information described by headers, paths, query strings, stage variables, or context variables request parameters.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html